# Connecting all vertices in polygon face

Tags: modeling

If you have some n-gon face, how to connect all the vertices so that you get all diagonals?

EDIT: n must be larger than 3.

Comment: Do you  mean triangles? Can you illustrate what it is that you are after?

Comment: @cegaton   , it can't be triangle because triangle does not have diagonals. I was asking how to get all diagonals in general n-gon.  I assumed n>3.

Comment: what do you mean by "diagonals"?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an n-gon face, then you can get a triangulated representation of that face using the following method (Bridge Edge Loops):

1. Select the object with this n-gon face.
2. Go into edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
3. Go into Face Select mode.
4. Select the n-gon face.
5. <kbd>X</kbd> >> Only Faces.
6. Go into Edge Select mode.
7. Select the edges that make up the perimeter of the original n-gon.
8. Visually De-Select two opposing edges.
9. <kbd>W</kbd> >> <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: Bridge Edge Loops]

---

After getting more feedback from the comments, Is this more along the lines of what you are after?:

[image: Diagonal Hatch Layout]

[image: Getting The Projected Geometry]

Comment: This are not all diagonals, right ? Is there a way that you could do that in one click ?

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the ngon face in edit mode and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > *Poke faces*